# Trying to save a file using file_put_contents()

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I'm trying to save a file like this:

```
echo file_put_contents("/tmp/foo.txt","Hello World. Testing!");
```

But the file `/tmp/foo.txt` is not created.

I'm on Ubuntu 18. My code is at `/var/www/html/index.php` and I'm requesting `localhost/index.php`.

Comment: Does your webserver account have access to `\tmp`

Comment: @RiggsFolly the permissions of `/tmp` directory are these: `drwxrwxrwt 30 root root 4096 Feb  6 13:01  .
`

Comment: Try writing the file to `file_put_contents("foo.txt","Hello World. Testing!");` does that work

Comment: See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)